# HOW TO SCHEDULE TWITTER POST VIA t command line (by Sferik)

Tags: twitter

Recently i installed t-command-line (twitter client) by Sferik.

It's a twitter client that based on command line.

I wanna ask, how can i schedule a post/tweet with t-command-line? But, i want it works like tweetdeck scheduler.

So i can post, for example, "abcdefghijklmn" at 09:00, but it will appear in my timeline at 12:00.

I know, it can be done with crontab. But with crontab, according to above example, you must be online at 12:00. I want "buffer style", like tweetdeck.

Is there anyone out there can solve this problem?? Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

You can't schedule tweets in sferik/t but you may want to take a look at this: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/buffer

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated.

Comment: @DerGolem The question was about scheduling a tweet with sferik/t and I answered without links: ("you can't").

The link was only aimed to broaden the selection possibilities.